# bash script issue - moving specific word to another place in the line

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, awk

I have this file:

```
# cat pt_Sed.txt
ULNET-PA,broker_etrade,broker_etrade_uk^M,BR    DELIVERTOCOMPID
ULNET-PA,broker_etrade,broker_etrade_uk^M,CO    TARGETSUBID
```

I want to arrange the lines so that they look like this:

```
ULNET-PA,broker_etrade,broker_etrade_uk^M,DELIVERTOCOMPID=BR
ULNET-PA,broker_etrade,broker_etrade_uk^M,TARGETSUBID=CO
```

I tried the following but does not seem to work as expected:

```
# x=`awk '{ print $NF }' pt_Sed2.txt`
# echo $x
# DELIVERTOCOMPID
# sed -re "s/\^M,*/&$x=/g" -e 's/ .*//' < pt_Sed.txt
# ULNET-PA,broker_etrade,broker_etrade_uk^M,DELIVERTOCOMPID=BR
# ULNET-PA,broker_etrade,broker_etrade_uk^M,DELIVERTOCOMPID=CO
```

Would you please suggest a solution? 
I would very much appreciate it!

Thanks,
Andrei

Comment: Is `^M` a carriage return in the example above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ sed -r 's/,([^[:space:],]+)[[:space:]]+(.*)/,\2=\1/' file
ULNET-PA,broker_etrade,broker_etrade_uk^M,DELIVERTOCOMPID=BR
ULNET-PA,broker_etrade,broker_etrade_uk^M,TARGETSUBID=CO
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use awk:

```
awk -F '[ ,]+' '{$0=$0 "=" $(NF-1); $(NF-1)=""; gsub(/,,/, ",")} 1' OFS=, file
```

**Testing:**

```
awk -F '[ ,]+' '{$0=$0 "=" $(NF-1); $(NF-1)=""; gsub(/,,/, ",")} 1' OFS=, file | cat -vte
ULNET-PA,broker_etrade,broker_etrade_uk^M,DELIVERTOCOMPID=BR$
ULNET-PA,broker_etrade,broker_etrade_uk^M,TARGETSUBID=CO$
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sed version:

```
sed 's/\(.*,\)\([^[:space:]]*\)[[:space:]]*\(.*\)/\1\3=\2/' pt_Sed.txt
```